# ssh bad configuration option when ssh the bastion server

Tags: command-line, ssh

here is my config file

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes

Host com-bastion
        Hostname com-bastion
        User hanumanth.rao
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        LocalForward 127.0.0.1:11445 search.com:443
        LocalForward 127.0.0.1:11446 api.com:443
        LocalForward 127.0.0.1:10443 auth.com:10443
        LocalForward 127.0.0.1:10444 prop..com:10444
```

I am getting the following error

```
ssh -vv hanumanth.rao@com-bastion
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/hanu/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/hanumanth/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/hanumanth/.ssh/config line 4: Applying options for com-bastion
/home/hanumanth/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: \342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202hostname
/home/hanumanth/.ssh/config: line 6: Bad configuration option: \342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202user
/home/hanumanth/.ssh/config: line 7: Bad configuration option: \342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202identityfile
/home/hanumanth/.ssh/config: line 8: Bad configuration option: \342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202\342\200\202localforward
/home/hanumanth/.ssh/config: line 9: Bad configuration option: \342\200\202\342\200\202\342\20
```

Comment: It looks like you created / edited the file in a word processor program that has indented the lines with Unicode en-spaces (octal `\342\200\202`) rather than ASCII whitespace characters.

Comment: It is in UTF-8 and and also tried saving in UTF-16, still the same. What is the correct format